# How list out all tables in MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, select

I'm using the code below to show the tables in my database.

I get "Connected to database" but nothing else. Is my code correct? can I use another way to get the info I need?

```
<?php 
$link = mssql_connect('HOST', 'user', 'pass');

if (!$link || !mssql_select_db('dbname', $link)) {
    die('Unable to connect or select database!');
}else{
echo"Connected to database";
}


$v = mssql_query("Select name from sysobjects where type like 'u'");
$row = mssql_fetch_array($v);

echo "<br>";  echo $row[0]; echo "<br>";


mssql_free_result($v);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but will this work: `mssql_fetch_array($v, MSSQL_NUM);`. Also, are you sure about the database selected?

Comment: Your query seems to work on MSSQL2000. Do you get an error or something?

Comment: No error, just connected to database and nothing else. I'm sure about the database .. how can I know if its a problem with permissions?  I'm not hosting the database and I need to know before contacting the host. Thanks again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alternate way, also fetches schema name

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG ,
        TABLE_SCHEMA ,
        TABLE_NAME ,
        TABLE_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: Thaks MadBender, but still no results, blank page. Do you think the problem may be database permissions or something like that? I'm not hosting the database and the people hosting it may have forgotten something. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try to connect and execute this query with some application like SSMS or SQL Explorer. It may give you more detailed error message.

Comment: Or maybe there are no tables in that DB

Comment: Hmm I wish I could install any of this in the host, but I cannot, another way of doing it? Thanks once again

Comment: Probably you're right. I'll get to the hosting service. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables;
```

Should do the magic :-D

And if u want to see all columns, i would do

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From Tablename;
```

so u'll get one row with all Columns, its not perfect but it does the trick if u just want to know sth

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
// Check if table exists
        $sqlExist = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'dem';";
        $stmtExist = sqlsrv_query( $conn_mssql, $sqlExist );
        $exist = $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtExist, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($exist == "") {
          echo "Die abgefragte Tabelle existiert nicht oder ist nicht erreichbar!";
        } else {
          // MSSQL QUERY ITSELF
          $sql = "SELECT * from dem;";
          $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn_mssql, $sql );
          if( $stmt === false) {
              die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
          }

          while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['cdemo2'] . ", " . $row['cdemo1'] . "<br>";
          }

          sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

        }
```